# Beaglebone black gpio pin out not as expected, LED blink program

Tags: c++, embedded, gpio, beagleboneblack

Im follwoing this guide: https://www.teachmemicro.com/beaglebone-black-blink-led-using-c/
And when connecting at P9_13 i do not get any LED Blinking. ( I also tried to set it manually, and can check that gpio is high, but LED is still dark).

I move the right-hand side wire (green) from the breadboard to P9_2 and P9_4 and the LED light up confirming that the wiring is correct. (according to this: https://vadl.github.io/beagleboneblack/2016/07/29/setting-up-bbb-gpio that should be VDD_3V3 and SYS_5V). If i move it to P9_5 the LED does NOT light up, is there no power here?

P9_13 as used in the guide is UART4_TXD, is that the one I'm supposed to use for LED blinking following this tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guide actually is referencing P9, while shematic is according to P8.

And in addition, the program should use gpio26 (not gpio23) if using P8 Header (Atleast for my board).

UART is used for serial commnunication, so i guess that is not a general purpose io....
Anyway, question solved after realizing this :)